# Pass Clickable dynamic value into react-i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I'm passing the value dynamically, but I want to redirect to another page when this value is clicked. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code example

```
// Page
t('product_create', {product_name: product_name, user_name: user_name} )

//Translation JSON File
"product_create": "{{product_name}} was created by {{user_name}}"
```

I want to make product name and user name clickable

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

```
// JSX 

<Trans i18nKey="product_create">
  <Link to={`product/${product.id}`}>{{product_name}}</Link>
  <Link to={`user/${user.id}`}>{{user_name}}</Link>
</Trans>

// JSON File
  
  "product_create": "<1>{{product_name}}</1> Created By <1>{{user_name}}</1>"
```